# Как исправить залипание кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, button

В кратце. Модифицированный клиент Спотифая. Расширение на JS добавляет кнопку.
Но есть проблема. Кнопка "**залипает**". Она подсвечивается, будто курсор на ней, до тех пор, пока я не нажму что нибудь другое, или в пустое место.
При чем нажатия на панели плеера всё ещё оставляют её "залипшей".

[image: Залипшая кнопка]

Код всего расширения:

```
(function spotifyLyrics() {
if (!Spicetify.LocalStorage) {
    setTimeout(spotifyLyrics, 1000);
    return;
}

function createLyricsButton() {
    const b = document.createElement("a");
    b.classList.add("button");
    b.innerText = "LYRICS";
    b.setAttribute('href','spotify:app:genius')
    b.draggable = false
    b.onclick = () => {
        if (document.getElementById().style.display === "block") {
            closeNav();
        } else {
            openNav();
        }
    };
    return b;
}
document.querySelector('.LeftSidebar .LeftSidebar__scroll-section .LeftSidebar__section').classList.add('hidden');
const extraControlsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("extra-controls-container");
extraControlsContainer[0].prepend(createLyricsButton()); // prepend = append before all
```

})();

Однако, если добавить в классы button-queue что бы стало:

```
b.classList.add("button", "button-queue");
```

То кнопка работает как надо, не залипает, но становится слишком короткой, название не влезает. Что, впрочем не удивительно, класс взят от соседней кнопки-иконки.

[image: Кнопка не влезает]

В общем, прошу, помогите исправить пожалуйста код. Что бы и полное название было, и не залипала.

Comment: Вот видео, демонстрирующие залипание, в сравнении с другими кнопками, может поможет лучше понять. (Осторожно, в конце неожиданный звук) https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wpoP2PdkNgeQyg